# do something exactly when a quartz job is finished

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I need to do some action after my job finishes in Quartz.Net, how can I find out when the job is done to do something.

I've read about job listeners in Quartz.Net, but I'm not sure how to use them to achieve what I need. Can someone provide an example of how to implement a job listener to detect when a job has finished executing, and then perform a custom action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use trigger listeners where you have access to the job via context, triggercomplete method fires when the scheduler has finished the job.